# JAX pmap with multi-core CPU

Tags: multicore, jax, pmap

What is the correct method for using multiple CPU cores with `jax.pmap`?

The following example creates an environment variable for SPMD on CPU core backends, tests that JAX recognises the devices, and attempts a device lock.

```
import os
os.environ["XLA_FLAGS"] = '--xla_force_host_platform_device_count=2'

import jax as jx
import jax.numpy as jnp

jx.local_device_count()
# WARNING:absl:No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU. (Set TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 and rerun for more info.)
# 2

jx.devices("cpu")
# [CpuDevice(id=0), CpuDevice(id=1)]

def sfunc(x): while True: pass

jx.pmap(sfunc)(jnp.arange(2))
```

Executing from a jupyter kernel and observing `htop` shows that only one core is locked

[image: execute from jupyter kernel]

I receive the same output from `htop` when omitting the first two lines and running:

```
$ env XLA_FLAGS=--xla_force_host_platform_device_count=2 python test.py
```

Replacing `sfunc` with

```
def sfunc(x): return 2.0*x
```

and calling

```
jx.pmap(sfunc)(jnp.arange(2))
# ShardedDeviceArray([0., 2.], dtype=float32, weak_type=True)
```

does return a `SharedDeviecArray`.

Clearly I am not correctly configuring JAX/XLA to use two cores. What am I missing and what can I do to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are configuring the cores correctly (see e.g. [Issue #2714](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/2714)). The problem lies in your test function:

```py
def sfunc(x): while True: pass
```

This function gets stuck in an infinite loop *at trace-time*, not at run-time. Tracing happens in your host Python process on a single CPU (see [How to think in JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html) for an introduction to the idea of tracing within JAX transformations).

If you want to observe CPU usage at runtime, you'll have to use a function that finishes tracing and begins running. For that you could use any long-running function that actually produces results. Here is a simple example:

```py
def sfunc(x):
  for i in range(100):
    x = (x @ x)
  return x

jx.pmap(sfunc)(jnp.zeros((2, 1000, 1000)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jake - Locking during the graph build is obvious now that you've pointed it out. Having the active and passive typing used by the tracer abstracted can sometimes hide obvious errors - I didn't have my AD hat on when I tested this.