# JAX vmap vs pmap vs Python multiprocessing

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, jax, spmd

I am rewriting some code from pure Python to JAX. I have gotten to the point where in my old code, I was using Python's multiprocessing module to parallelize the evaluation of a function over all of the CPU cores in a single node as follows:

```py
# start pool process 
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10) # if node has 10 CPU cores, start 10 processes

# use pool.map to evaluate function(input) for each input in parallel
# suppose len(inputs) is very large and 10 inputs are processed in parallel at a time
# store the results in a list called out
out = pool.map(function,inputs)

# close pool processes to free memory
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I know that JAX has vmap and pmap, but I don't understand if either of those are a drop-in replacement for how I'm using multiprocessing.pool.map above.

1. Is `vmap(function,in_axes=0)(inputs)` distributing to all available CPU cores or what?
2. How is `pmap(function,in_axes=0)(inputs)` different from vmap and multiprocessing.pool.map?
3. Is my usage of multiprocessing.pool.map above an example of a "single-program, multiple-data (SPMD)" code that pmap is meant for?
4. When I actually do `pmap(function,in_axes=0)(inputs)` I get an error -- ValueError: compiling computation that requires 10 logical devices, but only 1 XLA devices are available (num_replicas=10, num_partitions=1) -- what does this mean?
5. Finally, my use case is very simple: I merely want to use some/all of the CPU cores on a single node (e.g., all 10 CPU cores on my Macbook). But I have heard about nesting pmap(vmap) -- is this used to parallelize over the cores of multiple connected nodes (say on a supercomputer)? This would be more akin to mpi4py rather than multiprocessing (the latter is restricted to a single node).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Is `vmap(function,in_axes=0)(inputs)` distributing to all available CPU cores or what?

No, `vmap` has nothing to do with parallelization. It is a vectorizing transformation, not a parallelizing transformation. In the course of normal operation, JAX may use multiple cores via XLA, so vmapped operations may also do this. But there's no explicit parallelization in `vmap`.

> 2. How is `pmap(function,in_axes=0)(inputs)` different from `vmap` and `multiprocessing.pool.map`?

`pmap` parallelizes over multiple XLA devices. `vmap` does not parallelize, but rather vectorizes on a single device. `multiprocessing` parallelizes over multiple Python processes.

> 3. Is my usage of multiprocessing.pool.map above an example of a "single-program, multiple-data (SPMD)" code that pmap is meant for?

Yes, it could be described as SPMD across multiple python processes.

> 4. When I actually do `pmap(function,in_axes=0)(inputs)` I get an error -- `ValueError: compiling computation that requires 10 logical devices, but only 1 XLA devices are available (num_replicas=10, num_partitions=1)` -- what does this mean?

`pmap` parallelizes over multiple XLA devices, and you have configured only a single XLA device, so the requested operation is not possible.

> 5. Finally, my use case is very simple: I merely want to use some/all of the CPU cores on a single node (e.g., all 10 CPU cores on my Macbook). But I have heard about nesting pmap(vmap) -- is this used to parallelize over the cores of multiple connected nodes (say on a supercomputer)? This would be more akin to mpi4py rather than multiprocessing (the latter is restricted to a single node).

Yes, I believe that `pmap` can be used to compute on multiple CPU cores. Whether it's nested with `vmap` is irrelevant. See [JAX pmap with multi-core CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72328521/jax-pmap-with-multi-core-cpu).

Note also that `jax.pmap` is deprecated in favor of the newer `jax.shard_map`, which is a much more flexible transformation for multi-device/multi-host computation. There's some info here: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Distributed_arrays_and_automatic_parallelization.html and https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jep/14273-shard-map.html

Comment: Thank you @jakevdp! I added the ```import os; os.environ["XLA_FLAGS"] = '--xla_force_host_platform_device_count=10'``` and indeed JAX is detecting 10 devices. But since I want to pmap over 1000 values which is larger than 10 devices available, I get another error message: ```ValueError: compiling computation that requires 1000 logical devices, but only 10 XLA devices are available (num_replicas=1000, num_partitions=1)```. I edited my post to include a minimal working example -- any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest making a new StackOverflow post if you're asking such a substantially different thing from the originally asked and answered question. Comment threads are not a great forum for answering complex questions.

Comment: That makes sense -- will do

Comment: @jakevp the new sharding API of JAX is very exciting.

Comment: @jakevdp I created a follow-up post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76544389/jax-pmap-requiring-more-devices-for-parallelization-than-available    It focuses on pmap but if it's better to address with shard_map I would be very curious to see your proposed fix (if you have time). Thank you so much!